# Keyup Event Handler in dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, append, addeventlistener, keyup, eventhandler

"Total" input doesn't work in the added elements! It works only in the first row! Any help please?
................................................................................................................................................................

```js
$(document).ready(function(){



 $('input').on('keyup', function () {
 $('#total').val($('#price').val() * $('#qua').val());
 });


 var i=1;
 $('#add_input').click( function(){

  var newInput = $('<tr id="row'+i+'"><div><td><input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Select Product"/></td><td><input type="text" name="des[]" placeholder="Product Description"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qua[]" id="qua" placeholder="Quantity"/></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" placeholder="Price"/></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total" placeholder="Total" readonly/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">Remove</button></td></div></tr>');

  i++;
  $('#dynamic').append(newInput);


 });



 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
 });


 $('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$('#add_me').serialize(),
   success: function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    $('#add_me')[0].reset();
   }
  });
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<form name="add_me" id="add_me">
<table id="dynamic">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Select Product"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="des" placeholder="Product Description"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="qua" id="qua" placeholder="Quantity"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total" readonly/></td>

 </tr>
 <button type="button" name="add" id="add_input">Add</button>
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').on('input', 'keyup', function () {
  var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('[data-price]').val();
  var qua = $(this).closest('tr').find('[data-qua]').val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('[data-total]').val( price * qua );
});
```

Because js runs once after you start page and create events. For use with dynamic added event, you have to make event on parent (im usually use `$('body')` )

also id must be unique, so better be

```
var newInput = $('<tr id="row'+i+'"><div><td><input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Select Product"/></td><td><input type="text" name="des[]" placeholder="Product Description"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qua[]" data-qua='' placeholder="Quantity"/></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" data-price='' placeholder="Price"/></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" data-total='' placeholder="Total" readonly/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">Remove</button></td></div></tr>');

<table id="dynamic">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Select Product"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="des" placeholder="Product Description"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qua" data-qua='' placeholder="Quantity"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" data-price='' placeholder="Price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" data-total='' placeholder="Total" readonly/></td>

</tr>
<button type="button" name="add" id="add_input">Add</button>
```

Comment: data-*=' ' didn't work for me, I had to change to a Class!
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Krityas Cause I made a mistake and wrote find('data-total') instead of find('[data-total]'), my bad, sry - editing now

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your new tr has no event binded to it. Solution :
Having an invisible row template after your table with class instead id in your input tags :

```
  <div style="display:none">
   <tr id="row_template">
    <td><input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Select Product"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="des" placeholder="Product Description"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qua" class="qua" placeholder="Quantity"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" class="price" placeholder="Price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" class="total" placeholder="Total" readonly/></td>
<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr> 
  </div>
```

And in your js :

```
 $('input.price,input.qua').on('keyup', function () {
 var parent_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
 parent_tr.find('.total').val(parent_tr.find('.price').val() * parent_tr.find('.qua').val());
 });

 var i=1;

    $('#add_input').click( function(){

    //to copy the template tr with its binding events (.on('keyup')...) :
    var newInput = $('#row_template').clone(true).attr("id",i);

    i++;

    $('#dynamic').append(newInput);
    });

 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: It will wont work. Cause he has 
  $('#total').val($('#price').val() * $('#qua').val());
And js will always take first element with that id.

Comment: Right, I have modified it

Comment: You solution is working great too!
Thank you so much for your time & help!